# We don't need this in our tag [inventory]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I don't think [inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inventory) (currently, 511 questions) should be part of our tag inventory.

It has no tag wiki, and its tag wiki excerpt consists solely of:

> Inventory Systems (DELETED)

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

No, it just informs the reader that the programming question somehow involves some kind of inventory, of which there are many. It doesn't tell the reader anything about what techniques might be involved or what a solution might involve.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No, inventories are not inherently on-topic. They are only on-topic if they relate to programming in some way.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, much programming work involves inventories, many of which are implemented using specific data structures or systems that already have their own tags.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, the tag is used for:

- Questions about inventory tracking systems for shops and warehouses.
- Questions about programming or querying video game inventory systems.
- Questions about performing automated inventories of existing systems (e.g. find all printers on the network).

Comment: These burnation request is never ending story, maybe one day we could get some more focus and target tags that are really problematic (The 500 questions in this tag is more or less like 500 questions in any tag), going down this street we need to burn [inventory-management] ... and then 5000 other useless tags.

Comment: @PetterFriberg have you not considered the [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory)?

Comment: @PetterFriberg, as long as users just post the burnination requests and not actually help out with them, we face the problem of burninations being never ending. Everybody wants to remove some tag or the other but nobody is willing to do the dirty work.

Comment: Yeah inventory is a broken window, but when I look around I see the place nuked!, maybe start with fixing the esential stuff and not worry about 5000 broken Windows, anyway to also address BR, if you change this from, "hey someone?!" can you fix this, to "can I clean this up", I will change my vote

Comment: @BhargavRao: I never understood why community need to put such a great efforts to manage tags (burninate, merge, synonym etc.). I am not saying its not needed at all; but the efforts can be reduced tremendously just by changing the way of creating tags. We have procedure to alter (rename, merge, synonym etc.) existing tag, which needs involvement of community and approval from experts from domain. Similarly, there should be procedure to create the tag. Just putting a new string in Tags box creates it and then community have to clean the..... No wonder why community don't care about it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg But at least SO now supply us with daily dose of puns thanks to these requests.

Comment: @AmitJoshi, feel free to post a new [feature-request] for that, but I'm quite sure that it has been asked multiple times before. I'm just a volunteer here like you, and have no power to change the creation of tags. The power that I have is to help our community clean up the mess, which even you, as a member of the community, have. I find it a bit unfortunate the people themselves aren't interested in this.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I am aware of it. I just tried to predict why community might not be taking interest in it. I have raised feature request (actually a discussion) yesterday [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386549/5779732).

Comment: @RobertColumbia Windows is always broken... Always.

Comment: @AmitJoshi with 10k reputation you cann access the [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) where we can see at least the new created tags and handle it early. The problem with a creation process is, how can we ask a question about the new tag, without bringing the question to this process, too?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: Yah... I was not aware about some of the facts and pit-falls and I learned those from the answer and comments on the discussion I raised. May be you should consider adding answer/comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386549/5779732) which may help future users.

Answer (score 6):

The tag description for this is nonsense, as is the tag name. If the tag is actually about inventory management systems, the tag should be called [Inventory-Management-System] or something like that, *not* the considerably more generic [inventory].

I totally agree with this being a Meta tag. It says little to nothing about what the actual subject is, nor does it say whether I'm likely to have any particular knowledge of the questions' actual topic.

I say we get rid of this.